# App page for an Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension for chrome (reminder extension), I want to list all the reminders added by the user in a separate tab. How do I do it? 
Currently, I have designed the popup form.

Do I need to write an app instead of extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a tab with an HTML file you pack with your extension, using the Chrome API:

```js
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html")
});
```

That page can use all Chrome APIs your extension can use. Note that `"tabs"` permission is not required for `tabs.create`

See [`tabs` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) for more details.

P.S. If you want a more app-like experience, you can [create a popup-type window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create):

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html"),
  type: "popup"
});
```